# How can I deploy Dash components on html script?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a website combine with Python Flask and HTML.

I made some functions that show graph like data visualization by routing them as a independent HTML scripts.

It was too static to deliver the insights I want to show.
I'd like to route and deploy Dash components (like figure) on my own html scripts by integrating exist project.

As far as I known, I need to declare `app.layout = html.Div([<contents>])` in advance before running server.
But by doing so, I couldn't load dash outputs.

This is the result I want.
[image: goal]

This is the source of app.py

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template, make_response, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash


server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)


df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/5d1ea79569ed194d432e56108a04d188/raw/a9f9e8076b837d541398e999dcbac2b2826a81f8/gdp-life-exp-2007.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdp per capita", y="life expectancy",
                 size="population", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                 log_x=True, size_max=60)


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    )
])
@server.route("/main")

def main():
    fig = app.layout
    return render_template('main.html',figure = fig)
```

This is my html script, main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Administrator
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hi this is the results!</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Dash outputs</h2>
        {{figure}}
        <div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To embed a Dash app as an iframe, run the dash app in a separate python process and then use the iframe markup to embed it by URL: <iframe src="the-url-of-your-dash-app" style="border: none;"/>

Above quote [source](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-with-flask-templating/6502).

I ran this for your code by using the following for `main.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Administrator
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hi this is the results!</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Dash outputs</h2>
        <iframe src="./" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"/>
        <div>
</body>

</html>
```

and modifying `main()`:

```
@server.route("/main")

def main():
    fig = app.layout
    return render_template('main.html')
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Can I ask one more thing? I’d like to communicate between flask and Dash. Could I retrieve Dash input to the flask app? 
Like if users changes Dash inputs then I want to show another data according to the changes, and show the different outputs to them.